# Python 3.6 DateTime Strptime Returns error while Python 3.7 works well

Tags: python, datetime, python-3.6, python-3.7

I just created a data type for my date data, which returns a `datetime.datetime` object

Here is the code:

```
import datetime


class Date:
    def __new__(cls, dateTime, *args, **kwargs):
        return datetime.datetime.strptime(dateTime, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z")
```

So everytime I give this class an [`ISO-8601`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) it should return the datetime object from the string...

Python 3.7 Example:

```
Date("2018-12-09T08:56:12.189Z")                                        
# Returns => datetime.datetime(2018, 12, 9, 8, 56, 12, 189000, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)
```

This works damn well, but when I use it on Python 3.6 or Python 3.5:

```
# Python 3.5 Traceback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/_strptime.py", line 510, in _strptime_datetime
    tt, fraction = _strptime(data_string, format)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/_strptime.py", line 343, in _strptime
    (data_string, format))
ValueError: time data '2018-12-09T08:56:12.189Z' does not match format '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z'

# Python 3.6 Traceback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/_strptime.py", line 565, in _strptime_datetime
    tt, fraction = _strptime(data_string, format)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/_strptime.py", line 362, in _strptime
    (data_string, format))
ValueError: time data '2018-12-09T08:56:12.189Z' does not match format '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z'
```

It's so weird, What causes the problem? How can I fix it?

Comment: The one you say is Python 3.6 is using modules from Python 3.5. That's a problem.

Comment: @user2357112 I didn't have Python 3.6 installed on my desktop, but it was installed on the server, So I used my python3.5, but I also checked it on the server with python3.6 and it had the same problem

Comment: @user2357112 Added Python 3.6 Traceback as well

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Ok, after 2 days, I checked the [Python 3.7 changelog](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/changelog.html), and I found out support for `Z` as a UTC offset was added in Python 3.7. See this [issue](https://bugs.python.org/issue31800) on the Python issue tracker, which is primarily about adding support for colons, but also mentions `Z` support further down the page. Also see the [`datetime` docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior), which say

> **Changed in version 3.7**: When the %z directive is provided to the strptime() method, the UTC offsets can have a colon as a separator between hours, minutes and seconds. For example, '+01:00:00' will be parsed as an offset of one hour. **In addition, providing 'Z' is identical to '+00:00'.**

On my class, I had to change the time format to this:

```
datetime.datetime.strptime(dateTime, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ")
```

I changed the `%z` at the end to `Z`, hardcoding the offset.