# Strange strptime error in python 3.5 and 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-datetime

The following code

```py
from datetime import datetime
dt = '2019-07-21T08:54:32.115285+00:00'
datetime.strptime(dt, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z')
```

throws the following exception in Python 3.5.3 and 3.6.8

```
ValueError: time data '2019-07-21T08:54:32.115285+00:00' does not match format '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z'
```

but works fine in Python 3.7.3.

I checked the 3.5 documentation but couldn't spot any changes. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `%z` directive only allows for a colon in the time zone starting with python 3.7.

See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53291250/python-3-6-datetime-strptime-returns-error-while-python-3-7-works-well)